# What's the best way (ES6 allowed) to extract values from an array and convert them to a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to take an array like so:

```
location: [
  {Id: "000-000", Name: "Foo"}, 
  {Id: "000-001", Name: "Bar"}, 
  ..etc
]
```

What's the most efficient/cleanest way to pull out the Ids and combine them into a single string while also appending in front of each value a static string ("&myId=")?

More succinctly, what's the most efficient way to turn the above array into the following end-result:

```
&myId=000-000&myId=000-001
```

As stated in the title, ES6 is acceptable to use if it offers the best method for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce`, extracting each `Id`:

```js
const location2 = [{Id: "000-000", Name: "Foo"}, {Id: "000-001", Name: "Bar"}];
console.log(
  location2.reduce((a, { Id }) => `${a}&myId=${Id}`, '')
);
```

While this is pretty clean and only requires iterating over each item once, in terms of *efficiency*, `for` loops are still more performant if you have a huge number of items in the array:

```js
const location2 = [{Id: "000-000", Name: "Foo"}, {Id: "000-001", Name: "Bar"}];
let output = '';
for (let i = 0, { length } = location2; i < length; i++) {
  output += '&myId=' + location2[i].Id;
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: "Efficient" and "clean" might be at odds here.  This is clean.  Not sure about efficient as it makes a new string N times.  Depends upon what the OP means by those phrases I guess.

Comment: To clarify on "efficient" and "clean" I guess I would rephrase to say I'm looking for the best balance of "code readability/clarity, maintainability, and speed."  I realize this may be subjective to each person, so any explanation as to why you feel one is better than another is always helpful (for others as well as myself).

Comment: @star-coder I prefer `reduce` over `map` / `join` because `reduce` doesn't require the creation of an intermediate array, and I prefer `reduce` over `for` because array methods have better abstraction and don't require manual iteration.

Comment: On the other hand, repeated concatenation is O(n^2), compared to O(n) for `join`.

Comment: @star-coder I'm with you. I've been programming for 40 years, yet I still find many of the clever uses of `reduce` to be confusing, and would rarely recommend them in solutions targeted towards novices. But to each his own.

Comment: @Barmar Repeated concatenation, as in what my code is doing? I don't see how it would be O(n^2), for each item in the array it's extracting the value from the `Id` property and concatenating it with the existing (singular, primitive) accumulator/output string to create another (singular) string. Each iteration, it runs some O(1) code, right?

Comment: A single concatenation is O(n), since it has to copy the two input strings into the result. Doing it each time through the loop makes it O(n^2).

Comment: @CertainPerformance It'd be best to use `encodeURLComponent` on those values too, for safety's sake.

Comment: @Barmar Repeated concatenation is only an issue if you assume the only available representation of a string is a flat list of characters, which is not the case. All the common JS engines use ropes, and flatten strings only when index-based operations are used. Given that, this code on modern engines with be `O(n)`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you, I had to look that up, it's very cool, and makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, it looks like you’re trying to concatenate URL parameters.
You can iterate over the `location` array and use the appropriate set of APIs for this: [`URLSearchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL).
In particular, you’re looking for the [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) method, which allows mapping multiple value to the same key.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(),
  locationArray = [
      {
        Id: "000-000",
        Name: "Foo"
      },
      {
        Id: "000-001",
        Name: "Bar"
      }
    ];

locationArray.forEach(({ Id }) => params.append("myId", Id));

console.log("Result as a string:", String(params));
console.log(`Explicitly calling \`String\` is usually not needed, since ${params} can just be interpolated, concatenated, or coerced to a String like this.`);
console.log("Result inside a URL:", String(Object.assign(new URL(location), { search: params })));
console.log("Result as a URLSearchParams object (look in the browser console (F12) for better formatting):", params);
```

But in general, using `map` and `join` seems efficient enough.

```js
const staticString = "&myId=",
  locationArray = [
      {
        Id: "000-000",
        Name: "Foo"
      },
      {
        Id: "000-001",
        Name: "Bar"
      }
    ],
  result = locationArray.map(({ Id }) => staticString + Id).join("");

// Or:
// result = staticString + locationArray.map(({ Id }) => Id).join(staticString);

console.log(result);
```

In the alternative, the first `staticString` may also be changed to `"?myId="`, since this looks like query parameters.

But it’s important to use the `URLSearchParams` API if you’re actually using URL parameters, so that the data is correctly encoded.
Try both approaches with one of the `Id`s having the value `"1&myId=2"` and you’ll quickly notice the benefit of the `URLSearchParams` API.
This API also needs to be used to decode everything again.