# What is the ideal way to transform an object into an array holding multiple objects in Javascript? (ES6 allowed)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an object like so:

```
foo: {
  someGuid: someString,
  someGuid: someString,
  someGuid: someString
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the best ways to insert it into an existing object as an array of objects as id/value pairs:

```
bar: {
  someOtherInfo: someOtherValue,
  someOtherInfo: someOtherValue,
  baz: [
    {
      id: someGuid,
      value: someString
    },
    {
      id: someGuid,
      value: someString
    },
    {
      id: someGuid,
      value: someString
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm really interested in figuring out the best ways to accomplish this.  By "best," I mean a good balance between code clarity/simplicity and performance (or all of the above if that's possible).

I know there's multiple approaches to take to transforming this data, so I'm really curious what others have come up with, I feel this would be a good learning opportunity for myself and others.

Also, this is in a Vue app, if that makes a difference.  (I don't *think* there's a vue-specific way to do this, but if there is, I'm definitely interested in hearing how!)

---

The approach I've come up with so far has not worked, but here it is for those interested.  I believe I'm going about it all wrong (probably overcomplicating it).

my data:

```
originalObject: {
  someGuid: someString,
  someGuid: someString,
  someGuid: someString
}

newObject: {
        some: null,
        other: '1',
        stuff: null,
        irrelevant: null,
        toThis: null,
        problem: null,
        targetArray: [
          {},
        ],
      },
```

my logic:

```
someFunction() {
  const foo = this.originalObject;
  const bar = this.newObject.targetArray;
  const fooLength = Object.keys(foo).length;

  Object.keys(foo).forEach(function (key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fooLength; i++) {
      const foobar = bar[i];
      console.log(foobar.ItemAttributeId);
      console.log(foobar.Value);
      foobar.ItemAttributeId = key;
      foobar.Value = foo[key];

      bar.push({ ItemAttributeId: foobar.ItemAttributeId, Value: foobar.Value });
    }
  });
},
```

So I feel like I'm making this more complex than it needs to be.  Furthermore, the resulting output is incorrect (I'm somehow returning the value multiple times, but it seems a random number of multiples...sometimes it returns 4 times, sometimes 3, I'm trying to reason through why that is).  I feel like there's just a better way to start out and I missed it, and now I'm down a rabbit hole.

Comment: *"I know there's multiple approaches to take to transforming this data"* - what are the approaches you've come up with? What have you accomplished so far, and what is the specific problem you're trying to solve with it? Give a [mcve]. What exactly is a *"good balance"* to you? To me, the *"good learning opportunity"* here is for you to figure it out.

Comment: `Object.entries` and `.map` that?

Comment: Or `Object.keys().map()`, either way, some form of `transform object to array and return a new object for every property of the foo object`

Comment: As a side note... A fairly common pattern for this is a [to|from}pairs function that converts the object to an array of arrays : `[[someGuid, someString], [someGuid, someString], [someGuid, someString]]`

Comment: See also [your last effort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51092611/3001761) - SO isn't a code-writing service, as a senior dev you should be able to at least show a current implementation for problems like these and describe what good looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vue, you would use a computed property.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    foo: {
      someGuid1: "someString",
      someGuid2: "someString",
      someGuid3: "someString"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    baz(){
      // nothing special here-- just javascript
      return Object.entries(this.foo).map(([key,val]) => ({id: key, value: val}))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{baz}}
</div>
```

To add the array to some other object:

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    foo: {
      someGuid1: "someString",
      someGuid2: "someString",
      someGuid3: "someString"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bar(){
      // nothing special here-- just javascript
      return {
        some: "other",
        props: "that don't matter",
        baz: Object.entries(this.foo).map(([key,val]) => ({id: key, value: val}))
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<pre>
  {{bar}}
<pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` along with `Object.keys`:

```
this.newObject.targetArray = Object.keys(this.originalObject).reduce((array, key) => {
  array.push({
    id: key,
    value: this.originalObject[key],
  })

  return array
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two "popular" ways of doing this.

```
// You have this
const input = {
    foo: {
        someGuid1: "someString1",
        someGuid2: "someString2",
        someGuid3: "someString3"
    }
}

// You want this:
[
    {id: "someGuid1", value: "someString1"},
    {id: "someGuid2", value: "someString2"},
    {id: "someGuid3", value: "someString3"}
];
```

The imperative way:

```
const baz = [];

for (const [id, value] of Object.entries(input.foo)) {
    baz.push({ id, value });
}
```

The functional way:

```
const baz = Object.entries(input.foo).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));
```

In my opinion, you should always follow the style of the codebase you are working with if there is one, or the one you feel more comfortable with if there is no existing code.